# Which dependencies to create REST services on Tomcat7 (Netbeans project with Maven)

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, netbeans, glassfish

My webapp includes REST web services and is running on GlassFish 3.1.2.

I would like to run this app on Tomcat 7 instead of GlassFish. What dependencies should I add and remove to enable REST services on Tomcat?

(At the moment I just changed "GlassFish" to "Tomcat" in the "Run" menu of Netbeans, but my http requests give a 404.)

Note: this is a Maven project on Netbeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is the list of dependencies you may need. Please note I just put latest version but you may want to use a different version. Please also check for compatibility of these versions with each other.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Needed if you are using jackson to parse json

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

This is what I am using on my tomcat but little bit older versions

**Now about your 404**
First check if the dependencies fix your problem. 404 may be an issue from some thing not configured right in your web.xml as well.

I hope it helps you solve your problem :)